# Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'fadeIn'

Tags: swift

Currently working on making an image fade in and out. I created two functions 'fadeIn' and 'fadeOut' they seem right to me but I can't seem to get them working. I keep getting Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'fadeIn'.

```
var imageView : UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.center = self.view.center
        imageView.image = image
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.isHidden = true
        imageView.alpha = 0
        imageView.fadeIn()

        func fadeIn(withDuration duration: TimeInterval = 1.0) {
            UIImageView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                self.imageView.alpha = 1.0
            })
        }
        func fadeOut(withDuration duration: TimeInterval = 1.0) {
            UIImageView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                self.imageView.alpha = 0.0
            })
        }
```

Comment: func fadeIn within viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move these funcs to an extension on `UIImageView`, rather than have them in `viewDidLoad`

```
class myViewController: UIViewController { 

    func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        imageView.fadeIn()
     }
}

extension UIImageView {

    func fadeIn(withDuration duration: TimeInterval = 1) {
         UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
             self.alpha = 1.0
         }
    }
    func fadeOut(withDuration duration: TimeInterval = 1) {
        UIiew.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            self.alpha = 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No - generally you don't have funcs within funcs (although you can). Move them outside `viewDidLoad`. But you should probably be calling `fadeIn()` from `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Okay, So I pasted your extension and I'm getting the error “Declaration is only valid at file scope”.

Comment: This extension should be outside your view controller's class.

Comment: Okay that worked, I created my viewDidAppear and put in fadeIn() but I'm getting the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'fadeIn'"

Comment: `fadeIn()` is now a func on `UIImageView`, so you'll need to call `imageView.fadeIn()`